# Iteratively-Deepening Depth First Search (queue and non-queue)

Tags: c, graph, depth-first-search

I am aware that most 'generic' BFS algorithms that use a queue also check for uniqueness of visitation to 'speed things up' as it were, but I'm a bit unclear as to how to implement such a method as I'm still a newbie to graph theory.

Beyond any general critique, I am curious about how I can modify the `iddfs_queue()` function as to include this property. Also, what is a common heuristic about order of functions in a file - i.e. should functions in the code match the way they are in the prototype list or is this a moot point as functions generally (except, e.g., static helper functions) get squandered off to header files?

There are three traversals of the tree printed to `stdout` in the following code, one showing pre-order traversal, another showing an IDDFS, and another showing a psuedo-IDDFS (which enqueues and dequeues nodes and works with them in that manner). A fictitious function `iddfs_stack()` would print in level-order and in reverse, but I have not implemented that here.

Finally, is the `typedef`s name of `QueueSpace` lacking in legibility?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node {
    int item;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

//queue ADT details
typedef struct queueSpace QueueSpace;
struct queueSpace {
    Node* node;
    QueueSpace* next;
};
typedef struct queue Queue;
struct queue {
    QueueSpace* head;
    QueueSpace* tail;
};

//Tree functions
Node* generateTree();
Node* newNode(int value);
Node* insertIntoTree(Node* root, Node* newNode);
int treeHeight(Node* root);
void printTree(Node* root);
void printLevel(Node* root, int level);
void freeTree(Node* root);
void showcase();
//Queue Functions
Queue* createQueue();
QueueSpace* createQueueSpace(Node* node);
void enqueue(Queue* q, QueueSpace* space);
Node* dequeue(Queue* q);
void printQueue(Queue* q);
//Primary Iteratively-Deepening Depth First Search functions
void iddfs(Node* root);
void iddfs_queue(Node* root);
//generic helper functions
int max(int a, int b);

int main() {
    showcase();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

void printQueue(Queue* q) {
    if ( !q || !q->head ) return;
    printf("\n\n///Printing the queue///\n");
    QueueSpace* head = q->head;
    while ( head ) {
        if ( head->node && head->node->item ) {
            printf("%d ", head->node->item);
        } else {
            printf(" NULL ");
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n///end of queue///\n");
}

void showcase() {
    Node* test = generateTree();
    printf("pre-order traversal: \n");
    printTree(test);
    printf("\niddfs traversal: \n");
    iddfs(test);
    printf("\niddfs (queue) traversal: \n");
    iddfs_queue(test);
    printf("\n");
    freeTree(test);
}

void freeTree(Node* root) {
    if ( !root ) return;
    freeTree(root->left);
    freeTree(root->right);
    free(root);
}

void printTree(Node* root) {
    if (!root) return;
    printf("%d ", root->item);
    printTree(root->left);
    printTree(root->right);
}

void iddfs(Node* root) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= treeHeight(root); i++) {
        printLevel(root, i);
    }
}

void iddfs_queue(Node* root) {
    Queue* q = createQueue(); 
    Node* tmp = root; 
    while ( tmp ) {
        printf("%d ", tmp->item);
        if ( tmp->left )
            enqueue(q, createQueueSpace(tmp->left));
        if ( tmp->right ) 
            enqueue(q, createQueueSpace(tmp->right));
        tmp = dequeue(q);
    }
}

//creates an empty queue 
Queue* createQueue() {
    Queue* q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
    return q;
}

//generate a space in the queue with node
QueueSpace* createQueueSpace(Node* node) {
    QueueSpace* space = malloc(sizeof(*space));
    space->node = node;
    space->next = NULL;
    return space;
}

//enqueue single node onto q
//currently does not enforce a size limit
void enqueue(Queue* q, QueueSpace* space) {
    if ( !q || !space ) return;
    if ( !q->head ) {
        q->head = space;
        q->tail = space;
    } else {
        q->tail->next = space;
        q->tail = space;
    }
}

//Dequeue the head of q and reassign head
Node* dequeue(Queue* q) {
    if ( !q || !q->head ) return NULL;
    Node* head = q->head->node;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    return head;
}

void printLevel(Node* root, int level) {
    if (!root) {
        return;
    } 
    if ( level == 0 ) {
        printf("%d ", root->item);
    } else if ( level > 0 ) {
        printLevel(root->left, level-1);
        printLevel(root->right, level-1);
    } //else, do nothing.
}

Node* insertIntoTree(Node* root, Node* newNode) {
    if ( !root ) {
        return root;
    } else {
        if ( newNode->item < root->item )  {
            if ( root->left ) {
                insertIntoTree(root->left, newNode);
            } else {
                root->left = newNode;
            }
        } else {
            if ( root->right ) {
                insertIntoTree(root->right, newNode);
            } else {
                root->right = newNode;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
}

Node* newNode(int value) {
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    newNode->item = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

Node* generateTree() {
    Node* root = newNode(5);
    insertIntoTree(root, newNode(8));
    insertIntoTree(root, newNode(6));
    insertIntoTree(root, newNode(2));
    insertIntoTree(root, newNode(9));
    insertIntoTree(root, newNode(1));
    insertIntoTree(root, newNode(0));
    return root;
}

int treeHeight(Node* root) {
    if ( !root ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return max(treeHeight(root->left), treeHeight(root->right)) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `MACRO` is bad, you should use something like `#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))`(which still wouldn't be completely right). See answers of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3437404) for how to define MIN MAX Macros.

Comment: Didn't think of that, thanks for the helpful reference.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor observations -

`struct` definitions

> ```
> typedef struct queue Queue;
> struct queue {
>     QueueSpace* head;
>     QueueSpace* tail;
> };
> ```

Why not do something like this:

> ```
> typedef struct Queue {
>     QueueSpace* head;
>     QueueSpace* tail;
> } Queue;
> ```

Comment: Although it turns the typedef into a one-liner, it's not immediately apparent that `Queue` is the typedef or if `Queue` is a variable of type `struct Queue`. I used to separate the case of the tag and the typedef so they were distinct, but  [after some reading](http://www.amazon.com/Expert-Programming-Peter-van-Linden/dp/0131774298/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1421402822&sr=8-1&keywords=deep+c+secrets) I felt otherwise about the combination in general so my preference is to separate the two.